# Monotonically decreasing Scrollbar offset when scrolling back in a BoxScrollView

Tags: flutter

I have a `BoxScrollView` wrapped by a `Scrollbar` with infinite scrolling. When I scroll down the item list, the `maxScrollExtent` increases, which is expected because the `BoxScrollView` lazily fetches more items and build them on the fly. However, when I scroll up, the `maxScrollExtent` also decreases. This leads to a undesirable effect that the scroll bar's relative position moves up and down during the scrolling.

To demostrate the issue, I printed the offset in `ScrollController`'s listener:

```
void _scrollListener() {
  print('position: ${_scrollController.offset / _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent}.');
  print('scrolled ${_scrollController.offset} from ${_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent}');
}
```

Below is the log when I scrolled upwards from the bottom. You can see that the relative position of the scroll bar did not always decrease.

```
...
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.8462036114968551. scrolled 108355.94165760644 from 128049.4909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.8459486157033521. scrolled 108323.28957606442 from 128049.4909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.8457035244297643. scrolled 108291.90576325524 from 128049.4909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.8310705510684073. scrolled 108261.1430278965 from 130267.09090909091
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7862224497844074. scrolled 108230.6676896399 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7860029376799543. scrolled 108200.44985289735 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7857875441565938. scrolled 108170.79897628384 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7855780941454827. scrolled 108141.96627816338 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7853761739197692. scrolled 108114.17012345551 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7851825905782871. scrolled 108087.52161665194 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7849992386274147. scrolled 108062.28155377843 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7846584005157636. scrolled 108015.36208918138 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.7845020554285601. scrolled 107993.83976660883 from 137659.0909090909
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.82662656196699. scrolled 107973.21004543554 from 130619.09090909091
I/flutter (12255): position: 0.8245012044374859. scrolled 107933.05412395291 from 130907.09090909091

...
```

The reason is that the `Scrollbar`'s position is calculated using `offset / maxScrollExtent`, while `maxScrollExtent`
also changes as we scroll. How can I change `Scrollbar` so that its position can be calculated with a stable denominator, say the maximum of `maxScrollExtent`?